# Append data to another column in a CSV if duplicate is found in first column

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV with data such as:

```
somename1,value1
somename1,value2
somename1,value3
anothername1,anothervalue1
anothername1,anothervalue2
anothername1,anothervalue3
```

I would like to rewrite the CSV so that when a duplicate in column 1 is found, the the data is appended to a new column on the first entry.

For instance, the desired output would be :

```
somename1,value1,value2,value3
anothername1,anothervalue1,anothervalue2,anothervalue3
```

How can i do this in a shell script ?

TIA

Comment: apologies, i should have included my work so far. I've used awk '!seen[$1]++' to weed out the duplicate lines, but i don't know how, when i find a duplicate, to take the value in the second column and go backup the file to append it to the first occurrence of the value in the first column. Happy to be told its more than just a quick and simple solution. not looking for someone to write a whole raft of code...

Comment: @StuartHeron: Refer my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need much more than just removing duplicated lines when using *Awk*, you need a logic as below to create an array of elements for each unique entry in `$1`.

The solution creates a hash-map with unique values in `$1` working as indices of the array and elements as the value appended with a `,` separator.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; prev="";}{ if (prev != $1) {unique[$1]=$2;} else {unique[$1]=(unique[$1]","$2)} prev=$1; }END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' file
anothername1,anothervalue1,anothervalue2,anothervalue3
somename1,value1,value2,value3
```

A more readable version would be to have something like,

```
BEGIN {
    # set input and output field separator to ',' and initialize 
    # variable holding last instance of $1 to empty
    FS=OFS=","
    prev=""
}
{
    # Update the value of $2 directly in the hash array only when new
    # unique elements are found in $1

    if (prev != $1){
        unique[$1]=$2
    } 
    else {
        unique[$1]=(unique[$1]","$2)
    }   

    # Update the current $1    
    prev=$1
}
END {
    for (i in unique) {
    print i,unique[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    FILE=$1

    NAMES=`cut -d',' -f 1 $FILE | sort -u`

    for NAME in $NAMES; do
       echo -n "$NAME" 
       VALUES=`grep "$NAME" $FILE | cut -d',' -f2`
       for VAL in $VALUES; do
           echo -n ",$VAL"
       done
       echo ""
    done
```

running with your data generates:

```
>bash script.sh data1.txt
anothername1,anothervalue1,anothervalue2,anothervalue3
somename1,value1,value2,value3
```

the filename of your data has to be passed as parameter. output can be written to a new file by redirecting.

```
>bash script.sh data1.txt > data_new.txt
```